# Template registration with Azure Notification Hub

Tags: ios, asp.net, azure, azure-notificationhub

I'm developing an app with Xamarin and Asp.Net.

I'm trying to register a device in an Azure Notification Hub, but I'm having a little trouble. I've created a Sandbox certificate through the Apple Developer portal and uploaded it to Azure in Sandbox mode, and I'm using the correct provisioning profile when deploying my app to my device.

I'm also able to get the device token in `RegisteredForRemoteNotifications`, pass it to my Asp.Net backend and successfully call `NotificationHubClient.CreateAppleTemplateRegistrationAsync`, which doesn't produce any errors. However, I can't send a push notification because it doesn't look like my device is being registered with the correct platform. For example, see the image below.

[image: Device is not registering with platform]

Am I missing something? Or can someone help point me in the right direction of what I can do to figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've finally figured out the problem. If you're in Sandbox mode for Azure Notification Hubs, you have to use a **developer** provisioning profile, not a distribution profile. Only developer provisioning profiles can generate device tokens usable in Sandbox mode.